# Install packages into a custom Alpine Linux ISO?

Tags: iso, alpine-linux

I have followed the steps successfully as described below https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_make_a_custom_ISO_image_with_mkimage

I can add a package which will be available for apk add when running the live iso. However, I don't know how to install the package into the iso, so that the software is already installed when running the live iso.

Comment: have you edited the `apks="$apks ...` inside the `mkimg` profile script to make you package available during the live image run?

Comment: yes I did. Indeed, it makes the packages available during the live image run for apk add. But they are not installed. For example, I'd like to have vim in the live system straight after booting.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make a custom overlay before building the the iso.

You have an example in the [aports](https://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports) repo which is [scripts/genapkovl-dhcp.sh](https://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/tree/scripts/genapkovl-dhcp.sh).
Copy that file into genapkovl-mycustomiso.sh (same as mkimg.mycustomiso.sh)

The important part is to put the name of your package (ie: vim) in the /etc/apk/world file.

```
mkdir -p "$tmp"/etc/apk
makefile root:root 0644 "$tmp"/etc/apk/world <<EOF
alpine-base
vim
EOF
```

also make sure to keep the rc_add lines (if you make your own overlay this symlinks are not added by default)

Then vim will be ready to use from boot, and also will be copied to disk if you make a hard-disk install.

Comment: In addition to the instructions mentioned above, also don't forget to reference your overlay in your mkimg.mycustomiso.sh script by adding apkovl="genapkovl-myoverlay.sh" in your profile function.