# Alpine Linux--Wifi Not Working

Tags: wifi, drivers, alpine-linux

I am running Alpine Linux from a custom ISO that I created using the extended profile as a base (following instructions [Install packages into a custom Alpine Linux ISO?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370895/install-packages-into-a-custom-alpine-linux-iso) and https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_make_a_custom_ISO_image_with_mkimage).

Everything works perfectly, except it does not detect any wifi adapter (internal or USB). Running `lshw` seems to indicate both are Realtek.

Just to be sure, I also did add the non-free b43 drivers as described here: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Connecting_to_a_wireless_access_point

I have the same problem when running from RAM as I do when running on the `sys` install to hard disk.

What am I missing here that I can't get the wifi working?

Comment: Does Wifi work when booting from the plain "extended ISO" image?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into some similar issues. For me I had to download some other firmware which could be loaded.

Check your output of `dmesg | grep firmware`

I had something like:

`b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.`

So I checked out some old documentation (specifically this part: "**If you are using the b43 driver from 3.2 kernel or newer:**"): http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/b43/

Using the steps defined there but using a newer version of the firmware from: http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/

Then running `modprobe b43` to reload the driver.

Now running `ip link` gave me a `wlan0` interface.

Good luck!