# Another way to add packages into an alpine linux iso

Tags: linux, iso, alpine-linux

I'm struggling with installing packages into my custom alpine-linux iso.
Following the official wiki on how to create a basic custom iso is working so far.

I've read following posts and tried some methods described in it:

- [Install packages into a custom Alpine Linux ISO?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370895/install-packages-into-a-custom-alpine-linux-iso) `[1]`
- [How to make a fully bootable ISO from Alpine Linux Edge?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511699/how-to-make-a-fully-bootable-iso-from-alpine-linux-edge) `[2]`

However, I'm not very happy with the solution described in `[1]`. Since I want to keep my world file clean and not fully bloated with my packages. (I do have an apkovl, since I need to start additional services on boot). Also, the packages have to be already installed automatically in the iso, and not after I typed `apk add` manually, [as described in the official wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_make_a_custom_ISO_image_with_mkimage#Making_packages_available_on_boot)

I've tried to proceed with method no. 4 described in `[2]`, where creating a script in `/etc/local.d` is needed. The script is being generated in the live-iso, but not executed, even if I add `local` to `sysinit`:

genapkovl-custom.sh:

```
rc_add local sysinit
```

The following is the script in `/etc/local.d`, which will be written, when `genapkovl-custom.sh` is executed:

genapkovl-custom.sh:

```
mkdir -p "$tmp"/etc/local.d
makefile root:root 0755 "$tmp"/etc/local.d/99-install.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/sh

apks="salt openjdk17-jre-haedless podman zsh mariadb"
apk update
for apk in \${apks}; do
    apk add "\$apk"
done
EOF
```

The `$apks` variable inside the custom-profile doesn't work for me. It only downloads the packages during iso creation, but does not install them.

Is there a different way to install packages inside the iso and ensure that they have been installed and are ready to use within the live environment, without the steps described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a project called teaiso from TeArch:
https://gitlab.com/tearch-linux/applications-and-tools/teaiso

It allows me to create my own customized alpine iso using an `airootfs` directory and customized packages.

For the people, who'd like also a custom iso, they have a pretty simple doc, which covers the basic needs for a custom alpine-distro.